# Having trouble rigging jacket to armature

Tags: rigging, armature

Whenever I parent the jacket to the armature it basically wonks out like so.

[image]

Promised to have it at least rigged by tomorrow

Here is the .blend in google drive since I don't know how to upload it here

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0GYtqKl9FvSVWVTQW5TejJaTWM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Pointing out that you have a deadline or otherwise are in a hurry to get your problem solved, probably won't do any good. The people here help out in their own time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your armature is not in rest pose, so when you parent the jacket it jumps to the not rested pose: applying this pose as rest pose is possible only if there aren't shape keys. As your shape keys are only in the face rig I went this way: selected one edge loop of the neck, Ctrl E Edge split, select a vertex of the body, Ctrl L to select all the body, P to separate the selection in a new object.
Back to object mode select the new body object and delete all shape keys, then apply the armature modifier.
Then select the armature and apply the current pose as rest pose. Select the body, add an armature modifier in the stack and choose the right armature (as showed in the picture). Select the face, shift select the body, Ctrl J to join them; then select the edgeloops in the neck zone and remove doubles to reconnect the two spare parts.

At this point you can parent your jacket to the rest posed armature.

As it's maden of more than 60K vertices, all triangles, it will deform not so well, will slow down all the animation process, and will need a lot of manual weight adjusting, also because the rig is quite complicated: I don't think it's a one day task: I would suggest you a retopo.

[image]